# Jenkins execute shell standard terminal required error

Tags: linux, bash, tomcat, amazon-web-services, jenkins

I have Jenkins master-slave setup and had a job that is going to execute on  slave machine.
Inside job configuration I have some Linux commands like:

1. shutdown the tomcat
2. start the tomcat

that are being executed in the Jenkins execute shell and require sudo permission.

When I switch the user using

```
su -
```

for running all the commands as root user It is giving me the error **standard in must be a tty**

Even I tried running the command with **sudo** but it failed.

Note : I have Jenkins Master-slave setup on AWS EC2 so I had few restrictions like :

1. I can not set password for root user
2. Can not give full access to the tomcat directory
3. Adding user to the sudoers

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Try this [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/397031/run-script-as-another-user-from-a-root-script-with-no-tty-stdin)

Comment: @Noproblem : good one but does not fulfill my requirements.